# Sublime Text: Only enable plugin for certain filetypes

Tags: haskell, editor, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using Sublime Test 3 and the SublimeHaskell plugin, and I'm looking for a way to only enable SublimeHaskell for certain filetypes or when certain files are present in the project.

One of the reasons SublimeText is so nice to use is how lightweight it is, supplying only what you need. Because of this, it feels a bit clunky to open sublime for something simple and non-haskell-related, like throwing together a script or something, and seeing that huge multi-core usage spike as Sublime Haskell inspects the database. It would be nice to have a preference option for ensuring Sublime Haskell only runs when a .hs file, or a folder/project with a .cabal file, is opened. I find myself disabling Sublime Haskell and only turning it on when I need it, which is really awkward.

Does anybody know of any plugins or ways to configure Sublime Text to work in this way?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to make a plugin only active sometimes. The best you can accomplish in that vein is to have the plugin do as little as possible when it's not needed (i.e. it is up the SublimeHaskell to notice that there is no appropriate file open and do nothing). That said, if you use Windows you could have a couple of almost-identically configured portable versions installed side by side, but that's klunky and heavy weight.

Comment: Thanks, I may just try to submit a pull request to SublimeHaskell, it should be straightforward given that I have other plugins a lot like SublimeHaskell that only activate when their relevant filetype is open (e.g. Omnisharp)